# How to make a diagonal matrix with canopy that has a displacement in the diagonal?

Tags: python, canopy

I need to create a diagonal matrix with its diagonal displaced left or right from the center any  help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the down-votes of your question suggest, you should try to explain your question in a better way. That being said, my best guess is that you're looking for superdiagonal and subdiagonal matrices; i.e.:

**Superdiagonal:**

```
0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0
0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0
```

**Subdiagonal:**

```
0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0
0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0
```

If that's the case, then you can use Numpy's `indices`:

```
import numpy as np
superdiagonal = np.zeros((4, 4))
i, j = np.indices(superdiagonal.shape)
superdiagonal[i == j-1] = 1
print(superdiagonal)
```

This will give you:

```
array([[ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

For subdiagonal, you just have to change the `i == j-1` part to `i == j+1`.